# Date disappears upon page refresh (NewsItem)

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

So I was learning how to customize Plone on https://training.plone.org/5/mastering-plone/zpt_2.html? and tried to follow the tutorial on adding the publishing date to my NewsItem posts. I’ve also tried to spice it up a bit and add a tiny icon to the side of the date.
Thing is, whenever I click on a news post I get the date it was posted on, but if I refresh the page, it simply disappears. It also happens if I go from one news post to another one. It will display on the first one I open, but if I come back and try another news page it won’t display the publishing date (it does if you just refresh the page).

Here’s the code I’m using :

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
    xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
    xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
    xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
    lang="en"
    metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
    i18n:domain="plone">


<metal:content-core fill-slot="content-core">
<metal:content-core define-macro="content-core"
                    tal:define="toc context/table_of_contents|nothing;">
<p>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" />
    ${python: plone_view.toLocalizedTime(context.Date(),long_format=1)}
</p>
  <div id="parent-fieldname-text"
      tal:condition="context/text"
      tal:content="structure python:context.text.output_relative_to(view.context)"
      tal:attributes="class python: toc and 'pat-autotoc' or ''" />
</metal:content-core>
</metal:content-core>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using a Plone 5 environment. Could it be because of some incompatibility (maybe jbot)?

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Thiago

Comment: I see you asked this question at https://community.plone.org/t/date-disappears-upon-page-refresh-newsitem/7138 already...